# Attach light acoustic tiles to typical fiber drop ceiling

Tags: tile, ceiling, acoustic

We have just build a small sound recording room at my office, walls and floor were done with no issue.

Now I'm looking at the ceiling, builders had to put in a drop ceiling with those typical boards you've seen everywhere.

I'm wondering how I can attach acoustic foam boards to this ceiling. I have tried double sided table (including the gorilla kind), construction adhesive and a couple of other things.

I need to get these boards up, their mass is about 300g for a full board, I want something that lets me stick it up and not worry about setting time.

Couple of things I should mention - The state of the drop ceiling doesn't matter, assume this is permanent so adhering to the tiles is not an issue. Remember that I can't press up very hard in most areas because it makes the ceiling go up.

I really thought a tube of construction adhesive would do it but it didn't work, so what can I use to get these tiles up?

Comment: I would research the foam for suitability as a ceiling cover. There are fire resistance requirements for most locals. Research "The Station" nightclub fire in Providence Rhode Island  to see how things can go wrong.

Comment: Typical drop ceiling panels **are** moderately acoustic. Drop ceiling tiles that are more seriously acoustic are available, and don't help you re-create The Station fire at your office. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Station_nightclub_fire Also, in many cases "had to use a drop ceiling" means there is required access (such as junction boxes) above that ceiling that does have to remain accessible.

Comment: What type of 'acoustic foam board'? Sound shaping, or penetration reduction?

Comment: @Tetsujin They are penetration reduction panels, we have plastic sound shaping panels as well but those have an adhesive backing that holds them fine.

The tiles are fire resistant and designed for this usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are domestic versions of acro-props, that work like the gun to squeeze mastic out of tubes. Use a piece of plywood around the same size as each tile, and these will hold the acoustic tiles in place until the adhesive has gone off. Slow job with just a couple of them, but you'll only do the job once - hopefully.

Or - take each tile down separately, and use adhesive to glue each acoustic tile to it.

Or - take a few tiles down, and rest the acoustics *on top* of the already suspended tiles, being careful with the last couple.Start at one end, work across. No adhesive needed either.

Comment: I'd go with option #3 - set the (appropriately fire-rated) sound-proofing foam _on top of_ the suspended ceiling. It could simply be placed on top of the tiles, or glued onto them. It might, actually, be easier to only glue a few on and mark them as the (last-in/first-out) tiles, then you can remove the foam & tiles in a 2-step process once there are some holes. I can see where super thick tiles could make removal more difficult.

Comment: Option 2 makes the most sense to me if not simply getting different drop ceiling panels, and using correctly fire rated acoustic treatments. Very likely the ceiling needs to remain accessible, so the tiles need to be removable, and removing them makes gluing things to them much simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately the drop ceiling tiles and acoustic tiles don't match in size and we have to work with the already delivered materials, there's also the issue of the ceiling supports which need to be covered as well. I think the acro-prop option might be best and I will confirm the answer if it works out.

It's a small room so even if we have to wait 15 minutes between putting up every couple of tiles it's not a big deal, can do other stuff in the meantime.